# Different tree hashes for same commit hash following git filter-repo

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I noticed this anomaly after running `git filter-repo` with the  `--replace-text` option on a repository, and it turns out it's reproducible in a more simple example.

It seems to violate one of the basic axioms of git, that if two commits have the same commit hash, they *are* the same commit, and therefore the tree contents and tree hash should be the same. (Excepting an astronomically unlikely collision, which wouldn't be reproducible using arbitrary data anyway).

Steps to repro:
Start with a freshly `init`ed repo (in directory `test_repo`) with the following very short history:

```
$ git log -p
commit 00fc46c3372592059ff63bc0dfb610d8e583fa3e (HEAD -> master)
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Thu Mar 9 10:04:38 2023 +0000

    second change

diff --git a/foo b/foo
index 8d5d568..243cf01 100644
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
 initial
 
+zzzzz
+

commit 19f6a7da7e8d9ca30a644872167bd7f17c3b5f92
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Thu Mar 9 10:04:23 2023 +0000

    blah

diff --git a/foo b/foo
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..8d5d568
--- /dev/null
+++ b/foo
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+initial
+
```

Make a text replacement file:
repl_file:

```
zzz==>yyyy
```

Clone it and perform the rewrite with git filter-repo:

```
git clone . ../test_repo_mod
cd ../test_repo_mod
git filter-repo --replace-text ../test_repo/repl_file
```

This works as expected. The replacements didn't affect the initial commit so it keeps the same hash, but the second commit has a different hash.

```
$ git show
commit a2b5518f99f3a42d55931021e4a79c59f0971734 (HEAD -> master)
Author: REDACTED
Date:   Thu Mar 9 10:04:38 2023 +0000

    second change

diff --git a/foo b/foo
index 8d5d568..5d94489 100644
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
 initial
 
+yyyyzz
+
```

However, things get weird when I want to bring in the old history:

```
$ git remote add prefilter ../test_repo
$ git fetch prefilter
[output removed]

$ git log --graph --all  --pretty=format:'(%D) H:%H - T:%T' 
* (master) H:a2b5518f99f3a42d55931021e4a79c59f0971734 - T:0258b53a79efebb3a1a18fae2f5f2b26338bfaf8
| * (HEAD, replaced, prefilter/master) H:00fc46c3372592059ff63bc0dfb610d8e583fa3e - T:0258b53a79efebb3a1a18fae2f5f2b26338bfaf8
|/  
* () H:19f6a7da7e8d9ca30a644872167bd7f17c3b5f92 - T:6f3003a0d9bd438abda8b48741b0b0a68925dcfc

$ cd ../test_repo
$ git log --graph --all  --pretty=format:'(%D) H:%H - T:%T' 
* (HEAD -> master) H:00fc46c3372592059ff63bc0dfb610d8e583fa3e - T:179af78895dc9c453df9caa00ed83b7c5bb9a378
* () H:19f6a7da7e8d9ca30a644872167bd7f17c3b5f92 - T:6f3003a0d9bd438abda8b48741b0b0a68925dcfc
```

As you can see, the commit with hash `00fc46c3372592059ff63bc0dfb610d8e583fa3e` has a different tree hash (and different contents) depending on which repo I'm viewing it in.

`git fsck` shows no errors, so I don't think it's `git filter-repo` corrupting the data.

ADDED: `git cat-file` output:

I've removed my name+email but that's the same each time.
Original repo:

```
$ git cat-file -p 00fc46c3372592059ff63bc0dfb610d8e583fa3e
tree 179af78895dc9c453df9caa00ed83b7c5bb9a378
parent 19f6a7da7e8d9ca30a644872167bd7f17c3b5f92
author REDACTED 1678356278 +0000
committer REDACTED 1678356278 +0000

second change
```

Filtered repo:

```
$ git cat-file -p 00fc46c3372592059ff63bc0dfb610d8e583fa3e
tree 0258b53a79efebb3a1a18fae2f5f2b26338bfaf8
parent 19f6a7da7e8d9ca30a644872167bd7f17c3b5f92
author REDACTED 1678356278 +0000
committer REDACTED 1678356278 +0000

second change
```

Comment: Ok.... interesting.... can you run `git cat-file -p 00fc46c3372592059ff63bc0dfb610d8e583fa3e` on both repos?

Comment: Have added this to the original post.

Comment: I've found that adding the remote is not actually necessary, simply referring to the old commit hash (which won't yet have been gc-ed) is enough.

Comment: unless somebody comes up with a nice explanation, that looks like a collision to me.

Comment: But, let's face it. You think it's that likely you will find a collision 1 - in a project that small 2 - on the same commit? I bet it's a mirage. I just don't know how to explain it.

Comment: There's no way this is a genuine hash collision, unless I somehow found one twice in a row with different data :)

Answer (score 2):

`git filter-repo` adds replacement refs for the old id's. Say `git replace --list`, that's what the "(HEAD, replaced" notation in your log is telling you. This allows text references in places like messages on rewritten commits to resolve to the corresponding commits in the rewritten histories.

You can shut off the replacement lookups with e.g.

```
git --no-replace-objects log --graph --all  --pretty=format:'(%D) H:%H - T:%T'
```